# How can I Insert Product type programmatically in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create product with grouped & variable type but It's not working when I try

```
$result=wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, 'variable', 'product_type', false );
```

It shows me invalid taxonomy error and is not inserting the product_type into the database and so is not setting the product type.

I have to update or insert my product_type just as it does in admin from add product option.

Please help with this.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check given example:

```
// An array of IDs of categories we to add to this post.
$cat_ids = array( 6, 8 );

/*
 * If this was coming from the database or another source, we would need to make sure
 * these were integers:

$cat_ids = array_map( 'intval', $cat_ids );
$cat_ids = array_unique( $cat_ids );

 */

// Add these categories, note the last argument is true.
$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( 42, $cat_ids, 'category', true );

if ( is_wp_error( $term_taxonomy_ids ) ) {
    // There was an error somewhere and the terms couldn't be set.
} else {
    // Success! These categories were added to the post.
}
```

Comment: I am using product_type taxonomy rather than category taxonomy.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution that I have to register the taxonomy as

```
register_taxonomy('product_type', array( 'product_type' ));
```

in my function(user-defined) in function.php before calling

```
wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, 'grouped', 'product_type', false );
```

So it create product type as I pass as grouped/variable/external/simple.

Comment: As I know this method is not proper since the taxonomy 'product_type' already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've written the code directly without using an action.

Try this,

```
function woo_set_type(){
    // Your code
    $result = wp_set_object_terms($product_id, 'simple','product_type');
}
add_action('init', 'woo_set_type');
```

I hope this helps

Comment: you are right but when I add action it's not working.

Comment: And if it work its taking the triple amount of time to load the products.

Comment: Note: you can use this function when you dynamically creating a product or if you need to change the type of products using id. I just added the answer to get an idea on how this needs to be implemented.

Comment: This method won't work (if you put the code directly into functions.php without wrapping inside a action) until you use the action/hook which suits your need.

Comment: I put the code directly into functions.php in my defined function without wrapping inside an action but it works quickly.

Comment: But what You would suggest for this b'coz I'm newbie here.